# Method called on crash iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

The problem is i want to send something to keychain right before my application will be terminated (and yes, i mean terminated - no in background).

I am pretty sure that `AppDelegate` method:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

works before on similar situations. But now, this method is never called.

I'm using Xcode 5 and develop for iOS 7.0

Comment: the `applicationWillTerminate:` will almost never be called, if the user closes your app it just gets purched from memory and no method will be called. The same will happen in low memory situation.

Comment: I know... i point this in my question

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate:` is being called when I kill from the multi tasker. But only if you app is not supend in the background.  But as far as I can tell you it does not give you a hole lot of time to do stuff.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to do this earlier? (e.g. when your app enters the background) There are many possible ways for your app to be terminated, some of which you can't catch at all (e.g. out of memory kills)

Comment: Becouse i handle differently background and terminated "mode". I need to separate it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure that `applicationWillTerminate:` is trigged when crashing.

I call during `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` :

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

Then, in your appDelegate, add :

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
    // Internal error reporting
}
```

Maybe you could save something to keychain from this method.

Comment: Excelent! Works great!

Comment: Can we send some data to the server using this method when crashed?

Comment: I've never tried, but it might be possible using `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`

Comment: @zbMax can you add swift code as well ? Thanks

Comment: sorry @Arshad Shaik but I'm not programming in swift (It was a long time ago and I almost not programming iOS app anymore).
But I'm pretty sure you could do it as those functions are available in swift : 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1409609-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler/

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4

Right this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()`:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
            print("Error Handling: ", exception)
            print("Error Handling callStackSymbols: ", exception.callStackSymbols)
        }
```

And any time when your app will crash then this block will be called.